# Unable to locate element XPath (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use this XPath in Selenium with Python but it's generating an error: 'Message: no such element: Unable to locate element':

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains (@class, "files-list-grid-view")]/div[1][contains (@class, "folder")]').click()
```

This code works in Dev Tools with $x().

[image]

I need a marked element.

Comment: what page is this on? can you show us the html structure? it's impossible to tell what's gone wrong from the information provided.

Comment: Post your HTML inside the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

If the `dataref` node value is unique and it is not changing dynamically then you can use the below xpath :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@dataref='folder-0']")
```

If you are still getting an error then try to give some delay before locating it like below :

```
from time import sleep

sleep(3)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@dataref='folder-0']")
# And perform some action here
```

Still it doesn't work then check for `frame` or `iframe` using `//iframe` or `//frame` locators and if there are any matches and the locator that you are trying to locate is in some frame then switch to it using the below line and try to run your code again :

```
from time import sleep

# Switch to corresponding frame
driver.switch_to_frame("frame locator")

# Wait for sometime
sleep(3)
# Try to find an element
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@dataref='folder-0']")
# And perform some action here
```

I hope it works...